# Tagging: animals vs wildlife?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Maybe this question is clear for native speakers, however I cannot find an answer to it.

What is the difference between the tags [animals](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals) and [wildlife](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife)? Should they be synonymized?

Comment: Perhaps animals could refer to domestic animals, such as pets or stock.

Comment: @ChrisMendez you´re right about this, I didn´t catch it. Still, it might be senseful to make them synonyms since the one is enclosed in the other and the difference might be too small to keep to different tags...

Answer (score 4):

There are 24 posts tagged [wildlife](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife), all of which refer to wild animals; and 15 tagged [animals](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals) of which 13 are actually about wildlife.

So only 2 refer to domesticated animals - I'm tempted to think this isn't enough of a requirement.

I'll wait for other views, but I'm tempted to make them synonyms as per Paul's suggestion.

Comment: I've seen two posts today that were tagged both wildlife and animals. Should we revisit this issue and synonomize and/or create a new tag like Ricketyship suggested?

Answer (score 4):

Animals can refer to wild as well as domesticated. Wildlife comprises of a wide variety of topics. Wildlife might refer to animals or birds or reptiles. Clearly, there's a big difference between the two. However, I suggest migrating all the animal tags which relate to wildlife to wildlife tag and renaming animal tag to domesticated-animals tag. That would clear the confusion.