# What is the difference between wildlife and animals?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

**Update**

I merged wildlife into animals.

**End Update**

We have two very similar tags [wildlife](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife) and [animals](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals). The more I look at this, the more it seems that the difference is too small to justify two tags.

For instance,

- [11 questions are tagged with both.](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife+animals)
- [8 with both wildlife and animal-identification](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife+animal-identification)
- [12 with both wildlife and animal-behavior](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife+animal-behaviour)
- [Of the 71 questions with the wildlife tag, only forty don't have an animal tag](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife+-sharks+-tigers+-bison+-animal-behaviour+-animals+-animal-identification+-animal-care?page=2&sort=active&pagesize=30)

If there is a difference between them, it would seem that all wildlife are animals but not all animals are wildlife.

This has been [brought up before](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/612/tagging-animals-vs-wildlife), but no action was taken.

I am thinking that it would be better to make wildlife a synonym of animals, does anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: I'm OK with just animals.  If one wants to be a splitter, one would have to have three tags, domestic animals, feral animals, and wild animals (or wildlife).  Because many people blur the distinction between feral and wild, this would not be useful.  So just go with the single tag animals, is my opinion.

Comment: I'm writing separate comments in case someone wants to refer to one and not the others. Wildlife also means plants and trees and other things that grow in nature without us specifically planting them. In addition to defining wildlife, we should probably define "wild," which might lead us to having more tags, which could be good or bad. For instance, I think I saw wild-camping in our list. This implies a different definition of "wild." I'll stop rambling for now and try to put together a more coherent answer. It's just very important to me that we don't do anything drastic. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue I don't think of plants as wildlife, but  [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wildlife) defines wildlife as  "Wild animals collectively; the native fauna (and sometimes flora) of a region".  Several other references also include flora in wildlife.  For our purposes, I don't think that makes sense.  For our purposes, a grizzly should not be lumped with a briar.  thus, I prefer animals to wildlife.  As for poison ivy and stinging nettles, can we just have a tag "plants"?

Comment: @ab2, thanks for taking the time to look up the meaning of "wildlife." Interestingly, we already have a [tag:plants] tag, so you may be on to something.

Comment: I feel the need to distinguish between wildlife and other domesticated animals like dogs (for hunting) and horses or mules for transportation in the wilds is in order here.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with merging [wildlife](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife) and [animals](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals), as both would be considered ***fauna***.

Plants would not fall under the designation of wildlife as they would be considered *flora*. If we wanted to eliminate any confusion, we could merge both the [wildlife](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildlife) and [animals](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals) under a [fauna](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fauna) tag, as well as create a [flora](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flora) tag.